# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'AñoPublicacion' at row 1

Tags: java

Estoy creando una aplicacion web sobre venta de comics en java, resulta que al momento de "insertar" me sale ese error que mostre en el titulo.

Insertar.jsp

Codigo HTML

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insertar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Insertar datos</h1>
        <form action="">
            <table border="1" width="250" align="center">
                <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtID"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Nombre del comic</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtNombre"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>ISBN</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtISBN"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Cantidad de paginas</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCantidad"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Año de publicacion</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtAño"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Autor</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtAutor"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Categoria</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCategoria"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Editorial</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtEditorial"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Precio</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtPrecio"></td>
                </tr><br>
                <td><input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo JAVA:

```
<% 
        if(request.getParameter("btnEnviar")!=null){
        String id=request.getParameter("txtID");
        String nombreComic=request.getParameter("txtNombre");
        String ISBN=request.getParameter("txtISBN");
        String cantidad=request.getParameter("txtCantidad");
        String año=request.getParameter("txtAño");
        String autor=request.getParameter("txtAutor");
        String categoria=request.getParameter("txtCategoria");
        String editorial=request.getParameter("txtEditorial");
        String precio=request.getParameter("txtPrecio");

        Connection cnx=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Statement sta=null;
            try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           cnx=DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventacomics?user=root&password=");
          sta=cnx.createStatement();
          sta.executeUpdate("insert into comics values('"+id+"','"+nombreComic+"','"+ISBN+"','"+cantidad+"','"+año+"','"+autor+"','"+categoria+"','"+editorial+"','"+precio+"')");
          request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            }catch(Exception e){out.print(e+"");}
                }


        %>
```

Comment: 1) Si defines los campos en el insert (`insert into comics(campoId, campoNombre, campoIsbn....) values (...)`) te será más fácil ver si has cruzado el orden de algún campo. 2) Se recomienda ENCARECIDAMENTE usar `PreparedStatement` en vez de `Statement` y pasar los valores como parámetros cuando al montar SQL se usan valores que no se controlan (como por ejemplo porque los introduce un usuario). Se intenta evitar SQL-injection.

Comment: Lo extraño es que, en el código compartido no veo que se use en ninguna parte una columna llamada `AñoPublicacion`.

Answer (score 1):

Las veces que he visto ese error suele ser de lado de MySql y significa que estás enviando un dato con mayor longitud o incompatible con el campo de la base de datos. En este caso particular diría que es porque en tu query:

```
sta.executeUpdate("insert into comics values('"+id+"','"+nombreComic+"','"+ISBN+"','"+cantidad+"','"+año+"','"+autor+"','"+categoria+"','"+editorial+"','"+precio+"')");
```

Cuando asignas año lo pones entre comillas simples, lo cual se interpreta como un string. Ante esto hay dos soluciones:

- La rápida: Quítale las comillas simples al campo año en esa línea.
- La recomendada: Envía los datos vía parámetros en tu query.

Un ejemplo sería:

```
Connection cnx=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement sta=null;
try {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventacomics?user=root&password=");
       sta = cnx.prepareStatement("Insert Into comics values(?,?,?)");
       sta.setInt(1, id);
       sta.setString(2, nombreComic);
       sta.setString(3, ISBN);
       ...
       sta.executeUpdate();
       sta.close();
       request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
}catch(Exception e){
       out.print(e+"");
}
```

La idea es que cada incógnita representa la posición de cada parámetro, por lo que deberías completar las incógnitas según parámetros tengas.

Comment: Ahora me sale este error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'AñoPublicacion' cannot be null

Comment: Pues basicamente ese error te dice que la variable "año" está recibiendo null, esto se debe muy probablemente a que la has declarado como String más arriba y que necesitas enviar un int para el campo; prueba cambiando String año por int año

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme, de verdad que no se que sera, ahora me sale error http status 500 - NumberFormatException:null, eso me aparecio cuando modifique string año por int año :(

Comment: Esto es un poco fuera de lo común, pero puede pasar; podría ser que como estás usando una "ñ", el campo no este siendo reconocido por eso, la solución sería que cambies de nombre el campo tanto en el html como en la recepción de datos de java, algo como "anio".

Comment: Algo más para enviar del modo que recibes los datos, necesitarás hacer un cast primero, de otro modo la aplicación estaría intentando guardar un string dentro de un int. Un ejemplo sería: int anio = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtAnio"));